# Force browser to clear cache once publish

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, tfs-2015

How can i add a suffix to all scripts src attribute on build before publish to the server.

> Example:
>
> Before: `<script src="js/app.js"></script>`
>
> After: `<script src="js/app.js?build=1.1.1"></script>`

This is AngularJS applications and having browser cache issue.

Using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is that you can use Replace Token task in your build. 
For example:

1. Modify your code like this:  `<script src="js/app.js#{JSVersion}#"></script>` and check in changes
2. Add a variable in your build definition (Variables tab. If it is a static value, you could specify ?build=1.1.1)
   [image]
3. Add Replace Tokens task to your build definition
   [image]
4. Save your build definition and queue build.

You can to do it through MSBuild, for example:

1. Add MSBuildTasks package to you app
2. Modify your JS reference code like this:
3. Add this code to your project file:

Code:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <HtmlFiles Include='Views\**\*.cshtml' />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild"> 
<FileUpdate  
   Files="@(HtmlFiles)"  
   Regex="#JSVersion#"  
   ReplacementText="?build=1.1" />
  <Message Text="Files: @(HtmlFiles)" Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Is the a way to do this when publishing form Visual Studio?

Comment: @123456789 You can to do it through MSBuild. (I updated my answer, you can check it)